# Total Variation of Subintervals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, continuity, bounded-variation

Studying functions of bounded variation, the following exercise showed up:

Let $I = [a,b]$ be an interval, $(E, \| \cdot\|)_E$ a normed vector space and $f \in BV(I, E)$ a function which is continuous at $a$. The space $BV(I, E)$ denotes the functions of bounded variation from $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ to $(E, \| \cdot\|)_E$.

1.) Show that for every $a_1 \in I$, there is $a_2 \in (a, a_1)$ with $Var(f, [a_2, a_1]) ≥ \frac{1}{2}Var(f, [a, a_1])$.

2.) if $f \in BV(I, E)$ is continuous at a point $C\in I$, then the function:
$$V_f:I\to[0,\infty], \; \; V_f(x) := Var(f, [a,x])$$ is also continuous at $C$.

**Notation**. To clarify sometimes $Var(f, [a, a_1])$ is written as $TV_f([a, a_1])$. This denotes the total variation of $f$ along the interval.

**My Attemp**. For the first one, I tried to consider a partition for the interval $[a, a_1]$. Then by continuity picked $a_2$ from $(a, a+\delta)$. With this point, I redefined two partitions, $P_1$ for $[a_2, a_1]$ and $P_2$ for $[a, a_2]$. Then wrote $Var_P(f, [a,a_1]) = Var_{P_2}(f, [a,a_2]) + Var_{P_1}(f, [a_2,a_1])$. However, *I do not know* how this term with $\frac{1}{2}$ could show up.

For the second exercise, I considered just the right continuity since the left continuity seems to appear by symmetry.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s(p,[a,b])=\sum_i|f(x_p-f(x_{i-1})|$ where $p$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ with points $x_i$. By definition, $V_f(a_1)-V_f(a)=\sup_p s(p, [a_1,a])$, so for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists some partition $p$ s.t. $V_f(a_1)-V_f(a)-\epsilon\le s(p,[a,a_1])$. By continuity at $a$ we can find some $\delta>0$ s.t. $V_f(a_1)-V_f(a)-\epsilon\le s(p,[a,a_1])-|f(a+\delta)-f(a)|$. Thus, if $a_2=a+\delta$, applying the reverse triangle inequality with the first term of $s(p,[a,a_1])$ and $|f(a_2)-f(a)|$ and using the definition of $V_f(a_1)-V_f(a_2)$ gives $V_f(a_1)-V_f(a)-\epsilon\le V_f(a_1)-V_f(a_2)$. This yields (1) when $\epsilon =\frac 12(V_f(a_1)-V_f(a))$ and yields right continuity of $V_f$ at $a$ by rearranging and noting that $V_f$ is increasing. This argument follows for any $x$ at which $f$ is continuous, and an analogous proof works for left continuity, thus furnishing (2).